# Set the size of an image within a picture box?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a picturebox with a tiled background image (plane white bitmap), and an "image" resource centered in the middle of it, I would like to chance the size of this centered image within the picturebox.

I tried:

```
picScaledRepresentation.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
picScaledRepresentation.Size = New Size(Width, Height)
```

But this just changed the the size of the whole picturebox, rather than the image within it.

Thanks, have a good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CenterImage` option does not allow for scaling etc. Take a look at the `PictureBoxSizeMode` Enumeration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx .

You probably want `StretchImage` , `AutoSize`, or `Zoom`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Padding` property of picture box to resize the picture in picture box
//First Set Size mode property of picture box

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Then

```
int padding = 0;
    private void btnAddView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //resultViewContainer.AddView("Data");   
        padding += 10;
        pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(padding);

    }

    private void pictureBox1_PaddingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;
        pic.Refresh();
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (padding >= 10)
        {
            padding -= 10;
        pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(padding);
        }

    }
```

Try to set your image size with the help of padding.. take an idea from this code snippet and implement that you want to do.